# R - write to file without colum 0 (write.csv or write.table)

Tags: r, csv

Suppose I have got the following data frame, named `highly expressed`

```
|    |New IDs         | Mean amast| Mean promast|Old IDs        |
|:---|:---------------|----------:|------------:|:--------------|
|44  |LdBPK_010009200 |   37.16175|     33.72800|LdBPK_010440.1 |
|46  |LdBPK_010009300 |   35.67275|     32.05529|LdBPK_010440.1 |
|83  |LdBPK_010012800 |    6.84300|     16.04800|LdBPK_010790.1 |
|84  |LdBPK_010012900 |    6.92775|     15.62371|LdBPK_010790.1 |
|93  |LdBPK_020005100 |    5.89950|     27.03371|LdBPK_210020.1 |
|300 |LdBPK_030014900 |    7.59575|     12.38143|LdBPK_030960.1 |
```

I now want to get a list containing exclusively the strings under "Old IDs" (i.e. the whole fourth column) for further data manipulation. When I write the following command:

```
write.table(highly_expressed$`Old IDs`, file = "test", quote = F, sep = "\t")
```

my output file contains two columns (an not only one, as I was expecting), as shown below:

```
|  X|x              |
|--:|:--------------|
|  1|LdBPK_010440.1 |
|  2|LdBPK_010440.1 |
|  3|LdBPK_010790.1 |
|  4|LdBPK_010790.1 |
|  5|LdBPK_210020.1 |
|  6|LdBPK_030960.1 |
```

Does anyone know a way to write to file without the column 0 (the indices 1, 2, 3, 4 etc)? Maybe using another function other than write.csv?

Comment: Try looking at the `row.names` argument to `write.table`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `row.names = FALSE` into `write.table()`.

Comment: It works, thanks (I also added `col.names = F` to get rid of the "x" on the top of my column)