# When I save the change made to the data variable, the old state is being saved. Where's the mistake?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

My input data is:

```
X, occupation ,  focc   , education  ,  race
1, 1 , sales  , professional ,  14  ,    non-black
2, 2 , craftsmen , sales    ,   13   ,    non-black
3, 3  ,  sales  ,  professional 16    ,    non-black
```

I delete the x column and save, but the unmodified state gets saved:

```
data <- read.csv("gss.csv")
data$X <- NULL
head(data)  
write.csv(data,file = "puregss.csv")
```

The unmodified state was saved:

```
head(read.csv("puregss.csv"))
```

I expected this output:

```
occupation ,  focc   , education  ,  race
1 , sales  , professional ,  14  ,    non-black
2 , craftsmen , sales    ,   13   ,    non-black
3  ,  sales  ,  professional 16    ,    non-black
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to [fix the formatting and indent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's almost illegible. Also it's unclear what your current and expected input and output are.

Comment: I added the first and final version of the expected data

Comment: Try `write.csv(data, "puregss.csv", row.names = FALSE)` ?

Comment: It was that simple. Thank you @Pelilican

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - write to file without colum 0 (write.csv or write.table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956981/r-write-to-file-without-colum-0-write-csv-or-write-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
write.csv(data, "puregss.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```